# Round launcher icon in android studio image asset

Tags: android, android-icons, adaptive-icon

I noticed that some app have circle shape on any devices.

**Circle image**

[image]

I want the same for my app. But Image Asset doesn't allow to choose transparent background for adaptive icons. I tried to set transparent png image as background but it fills [black color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DVVD.jpg) on my device.

**Black color image**

[image]

android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

[backgroud image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IO7K.png)

[foreground image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRXi7.png)

How to make an cirlce icon for all themes and devices?

Comment: make background of launcher icon to transparent

Comment: Post your drawable image

Comment: Are you added ` android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` on AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, I added android:roundIcon

Comment: If you want to use only this round shape icon then, You can directly copy your icon , and put into mipmap directory of your project and remove all older icons. And named it as old icon file.

Answer (score 0):

Make a round icon with transparent background. Add your icon in drawable or mipmap then go to manifest changes these two lines. You will be good to go for every device and theme

```
 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
 android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon"
```